# raspberry pi server not displaying website on mobile "google" correctly

Tags: html, css, raspberry-pi

(im learning html & css my first week so be easy on me :D )

okay, so i have set up an apache webserver on a raspberrypi4 to show a webpage,starting with a mobile responsive site first but what i cant figure out is why the site works perfectly fine on samsungs, firefox and even duckduckgo browsers including pc but when i try to open it with google it just does not work any ideas why. ?.

(edit-1)-i tried removing the video from the file but still showing white screen so im guessing its an issue with my code that the browser does not like or maybe the pi can not handle the files

(edit-2)- even stranger i tried this in the incognito browser and it worked! im really struggling to see the issue here ?

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: blanchedalmond;
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"poppins" ;
    src: url(/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf);
}
@font-face{
    font-family: "westcoast";
    src: url(/fonts/Shockwave.woff);
}
header{
    height: 90px;
}
#navbar{
    position: fixed;
    font-family: "poppins";
    background:black url(/images/suspectlogo3.png)no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position-x: right;
    border-bottom: solid thin red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
}
#navbar h1{
    font-family: "westcoast";
    color: white;
    border: outset thick red;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius:0;
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 30%
}
#navbar li{
    font-size: 3vw;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#navbar a{
    text-decoration:underlin;
    color: blanchedalmond;
}
#video1{
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.videobox{
    max-width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid thick red;
    background: black;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.videobox ol{
    font-family: "westcoast";
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
    top: 15%;
    left: 30%;
}
.videobox li{
    list-style: none;
    font-size:4vh ;
    color: white;
}
.videobox li:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <title>suspect nav</title>
        <meta charset="uft-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/home.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav id="navbar">
                <h1>SUSPECT</h1>
                <ol>
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SOCIAL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main class="videobox">
            <video id="video1" src="/video/suspect.mp4" autoplay loop controls></video>
                <ol>
                    <li>Annocements</li>
                    <li>Merch</li>
                    <li>Meets</li>
                    <li>Since2020</li>
                </ol>
        </main>
        <main class="videobox">
            <p>Lorem200 ipsum dolor sit amet consecteture quod rum labore alias deserunt esse earum.</p>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it was my phones (samsungs20)google application itself, i force unistalled it then re installed it since it worked on all other phones in my house